# how to store the result of a set operation into a variable

Tags: oracle, variables

i tried it this way

```
set @v1 := (SELECT SUBSTR(IFSC,1,4) FROM rtgs_new MINUS SELECT SUBSTR(IFSC,1,4) FROM rtgs_temp);
```

or

```
set @v1 = (SELECT SUBSTR(IFSC,1,4) FROM rtgs_new MINUS SELECT SUBSTR(IFSC,1,4) FROM rtgs_temp);
```

but i get this error:

```
SP2-0158: unknown SET option "@v1"
```

i want to use this variable to compare with and insert into another oracle table.

any information will be helpful.
thank you guys!

Comment: Are you trying to use SQL*Plus variables? Or does this need to work as a PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: Also, MINUS can return several rows, this won't fit into a single "variable".

Comment: Could you write more about what you need that for? Maybe creating a temporary table from the results of your queries would be enough (of course depending on what you really need the results for).

Comment: i wanted to insert into rtgs_new as colin has shown here

Comment: but i get error "not enough values"
new values of the table rtgs_new has to be inserted into rtgs_temp which has an additional column bank_id. how do i update it to max(bank_id)+1 for each insert as i want to insert only those that is not contained in rtgs_temp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to insert into another table, why don't you do that?

```
insert into another_table
SELECT SUBSTR(IFSC,1,4) FROM rtgs_new MINUS SELECT SUBSTR(IFSC,1,4) FROM rtgs_temp;
```

Comment: hey, it gives the error "not enough values"
how do i set the ID column to max(id)+1 every time i insert?
thanks for them help :)

Comment: created a sequence bank_id_seq.
but your solution would work if only i had just those columns. how do i insert the rest of them?
i am trying
'insert into rtgs_temp
(bank_id_seq.nextval,bank,select IFSC FROM rtgs_new MINUS SELECT IFSC FROM rtgs_temp,branchname,address from rtgs_new);'
and still looks like i need that variable